# Using .indexOn with nested nested keys in Firebase

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase PHP SDK and trying to find a way to use .indexOn Firebase rule on a nested nested key **userId**, I am wondering why I am not getting it right yet. Thanks in advance.

I have a table called "conversations" and the first level nest is the user id, then second level is the key

```
conversations
-->user1
   -->key1
      -->userId
   -->key2
      -->userId
-->user2
   -->key1
      -->userId
   -->key2
      -->userId
```

Following is the Firebase rule added,

```html
{
"rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null",
  "conversations": {
        ".indexOn": ["user/key/userId"]
        }   
  }
}
```

On the PHP level, I am trying to retrieve the data but failed,

```
$reference = $database->getReference('conversations/'.$request['userId'].'/')
                          ->orderByChild('userId')
                          ->equalTo('ABCD')
                          ->getValue();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes need to be defined on the level of the JSON where the query runs. Since you run a query on `/conversations/$uid`, that is also where you need to define rhe index.

So:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "conversations": {
      "$uid": {
        ".indexOn": ["userId"]
      }   
    }   
  }
}
```

Note that I also updated what you index on, to match with the value you pass into `orderByChild`.